# Is there a word for when something is both simulatneously true and untrue?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when something is both simulatneously true and not true? I will use this word to describe a situation.

Comment: What context? A proposition that is both true and untrue in philosophy or formal logic? Something which is undecidable? Non-dualistic concepts in quantum mechanics (Schrodinger's cat)? Non-dualistic ideas in religions such as Buddhism or Sufism? A statement which has two different meanings, one of which is true and one of which is false based on words with multiple meanings? A statement that may be taken ironically or literally? A word which is its own opposite? Or something else?

Comment: I think this is clearly looking for Paradox, which @GeorgeWhite supplied. Not sure why it was closed. "This statement is a lie" is a good example. If it is true, then it is false. If it is false, then it is true.

Comment: Can you be clearer with more context? You should give a sentence with lots of detail with a blank for your word, so we can see the context.

Comment: @GArthurBrown A good reason for closure is that if your guess is true (the question as it stands doesn't belong on a language site) it's a duplicate ([When something appears a certain way but is also its opposite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354674/when-something-appears-a-certain-way-but-is-also-its-opposite/354679#354679)). 'Paradox' appears in over 500 questions and answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or a **paradox**

merriam-webster.com/

> : a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common
> sense and yet is perhaps true

Answer (score 0):

This is a "contradiction".